# Book a room without a credit card?

Tags: hotels, payment-cards, toronto, booking.com

I'll be landing in Toronto on May 23, 2018. I have an immigrant visa (I'm from Iran) and it's my first time coming to Canada. I need to book a temporary room for my first few days until I find a place to settle down.

I tried to book a room through the booking.com website but in the payment options it mentions that they only accept credit cards. Even for hotels that accept cash on arrival, I must provide credit card information.

Booking a room with AirBNB is not an alternative: they ban people from Iran. I tried emailing them but got no response. Since I'm from Iran and Iranian banks are banned internationally, they can't provide credit cards to their account holders, so I don't have a credit card.

This is a great dilemma. How can I book a room without a credit card?

Comment: There are other sites like AirBNB (e.g. Wimdu), but you'll have to check what they require.

Comment: Are you currently located in Iran? Because if not you can buy some prepaid Visa cards for many locations worldwide

Comment: @Jay If you're arriving early enough, can you not just go into a bank, sign up for a bank account (Chequing account)  they will give you the debit card straight away then create an account on Airbnb with this card? This seems to me like the best option if the prepaid visa card do not work.

Comment: @phorce I will be in Toronto at 6:00 pm. no bank will be open.

Comment: @Hanky Panky  They don't accept prepaid visa or master cards.yes i'm in iran right now.

Comment: @Jay how are they going to find out which type of visa card is that? If you can get one from someone its perfectly fine to use regardless of what they say.

Comment: @Hanky Panky They may not find out in the time of booking online.but while i arrive they will ask me to show them the card and they can see that it's a prepaid card.it's written on the card.
so maybe for that they will cancel my booking.

Comment: No, it is your money you paid for the card. They are only concerned about the money being legal using a legal channel. Its none of their business to dictate you whether your card should be credit or debit or whether it belongs to an account or is a prepaid card

Comment: A newly-arrived immigrant would likely find it very difficult to get a bank account straightaway as they’d be unable to meet anti money laundering requirements, in particular proof of address.

Answer (score 5):

Booking.com  offers book without card you need to use fliters. [image][image]

Comment: the problem is that all hotels require a credit card for a deposit. Even if you pay at the property they still require you to have a credit card and put $100 down

Comment: @Phorce you mean when checking in at the property? Many do require a credit card, but others can take cash or not require a deposit at all if you pay upfront. This is usually more often the case in cheaper properties, and probably needs to be checked in advance to avoid any surprises. I believed there was another question on that topic recently.

Comment: The thing with booking.com filters is that i tried to check a filter called "without credit card" but in toronto there is only one place that shows up and from the reviews of the guests, staying in that place is a terrible choice. so i don't want to go to the only horrible place which accepts cash.
i seriously don't know what to do.

Comment: Jay you do not  need booking to go to hotel you can check any hotel without booking and pay them cash bro

Comment: Or simply call them bro

Comment: @Aneeq I try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

For hotels in Canada and the USA booking without a credit or debit card is no longer common. However you're not the first person to have this issue, some locals also book and stay at properties without using cards so many hotels have policies and ways to arrange this. Cardless bookings aren't normally possible through the automatic booking channels.

Many hotels have a policy of taking a cash deposit and/or requiring prepayment for "Cash Paying Guests" e.g. the [Omni King Edward's policy](https://www.omnihotels.com/hotels/toronto-king-edward/property-details/policies):

> Guests paying in cash must pay their room charges and taxes in full
>   with an additional $150 per day security deposit at the time of
>   check-in.

Some hotels do not allow bookings without credit cards like the [Holiday Inn Downtown Centre](https://www.ihg.com/holidayinn/hotels/us/en/toronto/yyzct/hoteldetail/events-facilities#):

> Credit card deposit and primary ID required for registration. No Cash or Debit will be accepted as deposit.

I'd suggest you find a suitable property and contact them directly by phone (or email) and inquire about how you can reserve your stay and check-in without a card.